# Convert [String] array to [uuid] array in Json REST api for hasura Graph Query

Tags: json, api, parsing, graphql, hasura

I am trying to send JSON data for graph ql query
JSON DATA:

```
{
    "dataIds": ["1224rr67-4b3e-473c-80a7-dccc480fb6c0", "28avxrb8-5ff6-45ef-b51b-d4f654321bf8"]
}
```

GRAPH QL query:

```
query GetDataByIds($dataIds: [uuid!]) {
  view_data(where: {data_id: {_in: $dataIds}}) {
    data_id
    created_on
    updated_on
  }
}
```

I am facing issue that as you see above JSON, the array is of type `[String]` (String array) but when i call Graph QL, it gives me this error:

```
{
    "path": "$",
    "error": "The variable type for the expected variable dataIds was not supported.",
    "code": "bad-request"
}
```

It means that `[String]` is not parsed to `[uuid]`, which i am assuming are equivalent.
Is there any way i can convert `[String]` to `[uuid]` in graph ql query (I cannot change the Database column which is of type `uuid`)
Anyone having solution, kindly share

Comment: We use a lot of such queries and see no problems with them. Although we use hasura 1.3: do you use hasura 2.x ?

Answer (score 0):

Where those Ids come from?
You can check [here](https://www.freecodeformat.com/validate-uuid-guid.php) that these Ids are not valid uuidv4.

So I think Hasura convert the type to `String` and not use type `uuid`.

Comment: In case of bad-fformatted uuids  hasura 1.3 returns:  "invalid input syntax for type uuid: \"hello\"" (I passed `["hello"]` on input)